# Identity Server 3: Method not found: 'System.String System.String.Format(System.IFormatProvider, System.String, System.Object)'

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.5, identityserver3, windows-server-2012-r2

This is my 3rd IdentityServer install and I've never come across this. The application worked fine in our Development environment which is Server 2012 R2 and has .NET 4.6 installed.

The PROD server is Server 2012 R2 and only .NET 4.5.2 installed. Installing 4.6 is not an option, wish it was. The server is pretty well locked down.

Here's the stack trace, I've tried digging through the code but I hit a dead end at Core\Configuration\Hosting\WebApiConfig.cs:38. I've forced the target framework to 4.5.1 just to see if it made a difference.

I've been testing it by going to .well-known/openid-configuration.

> [MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.String 
>   System.String.Format(System.IFormatProvider, System.String,
>   System.Object)'.]
>   System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue.CheckMediaTypeFormat(String
>   mediaType, String parameterName) +0
>   System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue..ctor(String mediaType)
>   +33    System.Net.Http.Formatting.MediaTypeConstants..cctor() +45
>
> [TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for
>   'System.Net.Http.Formatting.MediaTypeConstants' threw an exception.]
>   System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonMediaTypeFormatter..ctor() +99
>   System.Net.Http.Formatting.MediaTypeFormatterCollection.CreateDefaultFormatters()
>   +49    System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration..ctor(HttpRouteCollection routes) +255
>   IdentityServer3.Core.Configuration.Hosting.WebApiConfig.Configure(IdentityServerOptions
>   options, ILifetimeScope container) in
>   Core\Configuration\Hosting\WebApiConfig.cs:38
>   Owin.UseIdentityServerExtension.UseIdentityServer(IAppBuilder app,
>   IdentityServerOptions options) in Core\Configuration\AppBuilderExtensions\UseIdentityServerExtension.cs:109
>   Owin.MapExtensions.Map(IAppBuilder app, PathString pathMatch, Action 1
>   configuration) +240    Owin.MapExtensions.Map(IAppBuilder app, String
>   pathMatch, Action`1 configuration) +181
>   WEC.WebApp.IdSrv.Startup.Configuration(IAppBuilder app) in
>   C:\Projects\WEC.WebApp.Authentication\DEV\WEC.IdentityServer\WEC.WebApp.IdSrv\Startup.cs:44
>
> [TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of
>   an invocation.]    System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object
>   target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor) +0
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj,
>   Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments) +76
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>   +211    System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters) +35
>   Owin.Loader.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0(IAppBuilder
>   builder) +341
>   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinAppContext.Initialize(Action 1
>   startup) +1043
>   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpModule.InitializeBlueprint()
>   +119    System.Threading.LazyInitializer.EnsureInitializedCore(T& target, Boolean& initialized, Object& syncLock, Func`1 valueFactory)
>   +241    Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpModule.Init(HttpApplication
>   context) +129
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +571
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state,
>   MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +322
>   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context) +402
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr
>   appContext) +452
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Exception has been thrown by the target
>   of an invocation.]
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +646
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context)
>   +159    System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context) +778

Comment: Have you figured out what was the issue? We're facing a similar issue on Web App in Azure.